# Reading binary qr codes with pyzbar

Tags: python, qr-code, zbar

I am trying to encode some binary data into a QR code using the [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/) library then decode it using the [pyzbar](https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/) library, but it is not working properly. When it is decoding, the result is slightly changed and some bytes are added. I made this test script to demonstrate the problem:

```py
import qrcode
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, Decoded, ZBarSymbol


def test(data):
    code = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=6,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
        border=2,
    )

    code.add_data(data)
    code.make(fit=False)

    img = code.make_image().get_image()
    img.save("out.png")
    detections: list[Decoded] = decode(img, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
    if detections:
        decoded = detections[0].data
        print(data)
        print(data == decoded)
        if data != decoded:
            print(decoded)
            print(data.hex())
            print(decoded.hex())
        print()


# Plain text
test(b"Hello World!")
test(b"\x8bwhat is happening\x00\x34")
test(b"\x00huh??\x65")
test(b"r@mM-{\x8be\xcdTh\xf4G6W\xe8\x10\x81\x89W\xe7\x89\r\xa6)z~2]45pa.\xbak([%\x94\xd2\x80\x1fy\xc5bJ\x00")
```

Output:

```py
b'Hello World!'
True

b'\x8bwhat is happening\x004'
False
b'\xe4\xbb\x87hat is happening\x004'
8b776861742069732068617070656e696e670034
e4bb876861742069732068617070656e696e670034

b'\x00huh??e'
True

b'r@mM-{\x8be\xcdTh\xf4G6W\xe8\x10\x81\x89W\xe7\x89\r\xa6)z~2]45pa.\xbak([%\x94\xd2\x80\x1fy\xc5bJ\x00'
False
b'r@mM-{\xc2\x8be\xc3\x8dTh\xc3\xb4G6W\xc3\xa8\x10\xc2\x81\xc2\x89W\xc3\xa7\xc2\x89\r\xc2\xa6)z~2]45pa.\xc2\xbak([%\xc2\x94\xc3\x92\xc2\x80\x1fy\xc3\x85bJ\x00'
72406d4d2d7b8b65cd5468f4473657e810818957e7890da6297a7e325d343570612eba6b285b2594d2801f79c5624a00
72406d4d2d7bc28b65c38d5468c3b4473657c3a810c281c28957c3a7c2890dc2a6297a7e325d343570612ec2ba6b285b25c294c392c2801f79c385624a00
```

How could I fix this so that I can decode the QR code and get the same binary data that I used to make the QR code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was in the decoding by pyzbar. It was interpreting the binary data as text and trying to coerce it to some guessed encoding. As of [version 0.23.1](https://github.com/mchehab/zbar/releases/tag/0.23.1) of zbar, there is an undocumented config option to tell zbar to just output the raw binary of the QR code (as from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60518608/11578007)). Pyzbar, however, does not support this config option. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/pull/82) to add it, but I decided to instead just encode the data in [base45](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9285/) using [this library](https://pypi.org/project/base45/) since the slight increase in size is acceptable for my use case and then my program is not dependent on a specific zbar version.