# Python - is there a QR code scanner which can decode raw binary data?

Tags: python, qr-code, decoding

I believe I can successfully encode binary data as a QR code, but I'm struggling to decode that data.

The top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996101/storing-binary-data-in-qr-codes) suggests that QR code readers generally have issue decoding binary data:

> The problem comes from the decoding. Because most decoders will try to
> interpret it as text. But since it's binary data, you should not try
> to handle it as text. Even if you think you can convert it from text
> to binary, as you saw this may cause issues with values which are not
> valid text.

How true is this for Python packages? I've tried using `pyzbar` and `opencv`'s but to I've had no success (they work fine for `utf-8` strings). I'm also struggling to find useful documentation for pyzbar, while opencv's is not fruitful.

For completeness, here's an example QR code that I've created.

```
data = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00\x84\x00\x03\x02\x02\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\x08\x08\n\n\n\n\x08\x08\n\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\n\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\x08\n\x08\x08\x08\x08\n\n\n\x08\x08\r\r\n\x08\r\x08\x08\n\x08\x01\x03\x04\x04\x06\x05\x06\n\x06\x06\n\x0f\x0e\x0b\r\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x10\x10\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\r\r\r\x0f\r\x0f\x0f\x0f\r\r\r\r\x0f\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x01@\x02\x00\x03\x01\x11\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x02\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x05\x02\x03\x06\x01\x07\x00\x08\t\xff\xc4\x00C\x10\x00\x02\x01\x02\x04\x04\x03\x05\x06\x06\x01\x03\x03\x03\x05\x00\x01\x02\x11\x00\x03\x04\x12!1\x05\x06"AQaq\x07\x132\x81\xf0\x14\x91\xa1\xb1\xc1\xd1\x08\x15#B'
```

To generate the QR code from this byte string, I use the `segmo` library, as so:

```
qr = segno.make(data)
qr.save(path/to/output/file)
```

Here is the resulting QR code:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer the question of 'is there a QR code scanner which can decode raw binary data?' - but we can get around that by simply doing a base64. b64encode(<byte_string>) before creating the QR code. Then a base64. b64decode(<qrcodedata>).