# How QR code can also be executable program

Tags: binary, qr-code, executable

- QR code represent a data with limited size.
- inspired by [mattkc](https://www.mattkc.com/etc/snakeqr/)  project, I want to do the same in MacOC not in windows.

one thing I still don't fully see: how a binary which is stored in QR will be *automatically* executed by the machine?

**binary** is also **text** right?

scan I stored binary in QR code and get executed immediately.

Comment: I think you can start from how to [store binary data into qr code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996101/storing-binary-data-in-qr-codes)